# Can send some data from smart contract to an EOA by Solidity call statement?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, smart-contract

It is done by web3js sending some data from an EOA a contract by:

`myContract.methods.function().send({data:...});`

Can the same be done from contract to EOA by Solidity (I mean by `.call()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but it does not send anything, and the EOA address does not receive anything (because it doesn't have bytecode logic to receive)

```
contract Test {
    bool public success;
    bytes public data;
    function test (address target) public {
        (success, data) = address(target).call("0x1234");
    }
}
```

- If `target` is a contract, `success = true` if the call successful and `success = false` if the call reverted, depends on the logic of the target contract
- If `target` is a normal address (EOA), success is always `true`